# How to rename duplicate value on Perl so they can have their own unique name ,So they are not duplicate anymore

Tags: perl

So I encountered an issue with duplicate value.

```
$pdftitle = $2;
                $cleantitlepdf = substr($pdftitle , 0, 30 );
                $cleantitlepdf  =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//gmis;
                $uidname = $cleantitlepdf."UIDUL";
```

basically the $uidname has some duplicate value what I needed to do is not to remove the duplicate but to rename it so it will have its own unique name. so just for example.

$uidname = 04042020AmendmentUIDUL - There are 3 of this on the $uidname what I want is something like this.

```
04042020AmendmentUIDUL
04042020AmendmentUIDUL1
04042020AmendmentUIDUL2
```

Something like this? so they can have their own unique name. I'm not good with perl if anybody could help me on this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: How do you know that they are duplicate? Do you have them in a hash?

Comment: Basically that $uidname is inside of an foreach, I store the value on $pdftitle and kinda clean it and store it on $uidname. When I print $uidname inside the loop I notice alot of duplicates. I expect it to have duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

```perl
my %next_ids;

while (...) {
   ...

   my $uidname = $cleantitlepdf."UIDUL";
   $uidname .= $next_ids{ $uidname }++ // '';

   ...
}
```